# Run-time error using Dir function with wildcard to open file

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I am trying to use VBA to open a .xls file in a specific directory but am unable to do so because of a VBA run-time error. I need to use a wildcard in the path because the filename changes slightly month-to-month, but it always begins with "CB947." I need to copy data from the CB947 workbook into my Master workbook. Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim dpath, sFound As String

dpath = "C:\Users\gbrown\OneDrive - My Company\REVPRO\Input Data\2018\January\"

Set Master = ThisWorkbook
sFound = Dir(dpath & "\CB947*.xls")
Debug.Print dpath & sFound
If (sFound <> "") Then
    Workbooks.Open dpath & sFound
End If
```

When I get to the `Debug.print` command above, the Immediate window prints out the correct path and filename, so I know the script is locating the correct file. It just isn't able to open it. When I try and run the above code, I get the following error:

[image: VBA_error]

Is my DIR sytax incorrect or am I missing something else?

EDIT: here's what my `Debug.Print` command shows in the Immediate window:

```
C:\Users\gbrown\OneDrive - My Company\REVPRO\Input Data\2018\
January\CB947 (4).xls
```

Comment: You need a \ on the end of dpath if its a path.

Comment: As @AlexK. says you need a `\\` before the file's name

Comment: There must be some difference. Can you submit the Debug.Print output?

Comment: @AlexK., I tried adding that "\" at the end of dpath, but it still won't open

Comment: Now you have one too many `"\"` put it either at the end of `dpath` **OR** at the beginning of the file name.

Comment: @ScottCraner, it doesn't seem to make a difference - the `Debug.print` command still prints it out correctly and even when I removed on of the "\", I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on Option Explicit
2. You can't declare variables that way, dpath is a variant
3. You have two slashes in your path
4. Let's add vbNormal to your Dir call, just in case

**THIS WORKED FOR ME:**

```
    Dim dpath As String
    Dim sFound As String
    dpath = "C:\Users\gbrown\OneDrive - My Company\REVPRO\Input Data\2018\January\"
    sFound = Dir(dpath & "CB947*.xls", vbNormal)
    Debug.Print dpath & sFound
    If (sFound <> "") Then
        Workbooks.Open dpath & sFound
    End If
```

**NOTE:** If this isn't working for you, then there might be a permissions issue. The workbook might be locked or unavailable to be opened for some filesystem reason.

Comment: Thanks, @HackSlash - I think it is a permissions issue. I'm checking with our IT folks now about why the spreadsheet is being generated in Protected View. This must be why the script can't open it